# How can I turn off vim in terminal of Mac?

Tags: mongodb, vim, terminal

I was trying to setup Mongo DB Community on my Mac(m1).
I installed Home-brew first and followed the install instruction of the Mongo DB.
However I could not run the command brew and I found that it was the problem that I didn't set up the Path in the zshell. So I tried it with my terminal but It just got stuck in this here. I tried to escape it with the :wq, :q! commands and it works. but whenever I restart the terminal it goes right back to this screen not to main screen. How can I solve this problem? plz help :(
(Im trying to learning so I'm not familiar with the terminal and codes stuffs)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in this situation because you typed the wrong command in the terminal and I suspect it is because you copy-pasted it instead of typing it out.

Your command is helpfully spelled out in the title bar of the window:

```
$ vi ~/.zshrcexport PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:
```

Judging by the content of the buffer, it is almost certainly truncated and the actual command was probably:

```
$ vi ~/.zshrcexport PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

So what's wrong with that command? Everything, actually.

- For starter, it should have been:

  ```
  $ vi ~/.zshrc
  ```

  with `~/.zshrc` being your shell's main configuration file.

  Everything after that shouldn't be here.
- Vim, which is the program providing the `vi` command, takes one or more filenames as arguments. With that command, you told Vim to open two files:

  ```
  ~/.zshrcexport
  PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
  ```

  - the former is the one shown in your screenshot,
  - the latter is not shown but it is likely to have a rather long name,
  - neither of those files are supposed to exist.

How to get out of that mess?

- Assuming you are in the situation shown by that screenshot, do the following:

  1. Press the `esc` key to make sure you are in what is called "normal mode" in Vim.
  2. Press the `:` key to enter "command-line mode".
  3. **Type** `qa!`, then press the `return` or `↩︎` key.
- At that point you should be outside of Vim and in your shell. It is time to delete the non-wanted files you created with these two commands, each followed by a press on the `return` or `↩︎` key:

  ```
  $ rm ~/.zshrcexport
  $ rm PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Now you should finally be able to edit your shell's configuration file but I recommend you don't do it with the `vi` command. `nano` is a much simpler editor that doesn't require as much learning.

  1. Open the configuration file in `nano` with:

     ```
     $ nano ~/.zshrc
     ```
  2. Move around with your cursor keys until you find the right spot, just like in a regular text editor. The file is probably empty anyway.
  3. Type that "export" line:

     ```
     export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
     ```
  4. Press `control`+`X` to quit, as instructed at the bottom  of the screen.
  5. Press the appropriate key when asked if you want to write the file.
- Avoid `vi` or `vim` in the future until you actually *have* or *want* to learn it.

As for why you end up in Vim when you open a new terminal window I have no clue. Maybe another one of your mistakes?

Comment: thanks! It was my firs time to use vi so I knew nothing about commands and things. I will try as you wrote!

Comment: It worked! helped so much! Appreciate your helps!